# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

Tags: python3, kivy

A Noob here to python.
I am running Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) and I cant get Kivy to install properly for python3.  I have tried (https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) the installation process, but it doesn't pick up.
I wonder if I should try to install it via a .whl package (any source)? Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kivy - Multimedia / Multitouch framework in Python (Python 3) (*python3-kivy*) is in the default repositories in Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 18.10, 19.10 and 20.04. To install it, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-kivy
```

This package contains the Python 3 compatible version of the library. There is also another Python 2 compatible version of the library named *python-kivy*.

python3-kivy has been dropped from the default repositories in Ubuntu 19.04 because of a software bug that also affects python3-kivy in Ubuntu 18.04. There is a workaround for this bug which is described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153116/which-ubuntu-for-kivy-and-python3/1153168#1153168).

Answer (score 0):

- Please make sure your virtual averment is active.
- If not you can use bellow commands to install new virtual env.
- else activate your env.

> 1. sudo apt install python3-venv
> 2. python3 -m venv demoenv
> 3. source  demoenv/bin/activate

- Then do

> pip list or pip freeze

- Check your respective pip package is present or not (kivy).
- if not then install it again on same virtual env active terminal.
- then repeat above pip list command and verify your pip package.